# “Can’t select database” error installing WordPress with Wampserver

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, wamp, wampserver

I am having trouble connecting my database to WordPress using Wampserver at the wp-admin setup.

I am following the steps in this tutorial:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-your-windows-computer-using-wamp/

I've created a database in Wampserver with the name "test_db".

At WordPress setup I’m entering the following information:

```
Database Name: test_db
Username: root
Password:
Database Host: localhost
Table Prefix: wp_
```

I click submit, and I get this error page:

> ### Can’t select database
>
> We were able to connect to the database server (which means your
>   username and password is okay) but not able to select the test_db
>   database. Are you sure it exists? •   Does the user root have
>   permission to use the test_db database? • On some systems the name of
>   your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like
>   username_test_db. Could that be the problem? If you don’t know how to
>   set up a database you should contact your host. If all else fails you
>   may find help at the WordPress Support Forums.

I've tried using another database without an underscore, naming it "testdb". I still get "Can't select database" error.

I've also tried changing the privileges of the database. I went into Wampserver phpMyAdmin app. Under server 127.0.0.1 I went to the user accounts tab and selected Edit Privileges for the root localhost user. I clicked the database button. I picked the test_db item and clicked Go. I check marked the Check All box, then clicked Go. When I ran WordPress install I still got "Can't select database".

Help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The `root` user has the ability to do ANYTHING by default. That is your SuperUser account. Messing with it may have done more damage than good

Comment: Stick to database names without any `_` or any other non-simple characters

Comment: Maybe I wrote it confusing. I edited the privileges for the database by going thru a link next to root localhost user, but then I clicked database and just edited the privileges for the database, NOT for the entire root.

Comment: Like I said `root` is the super user It Can Do Anything OUT OF THE BOX

Comment: As I said above, I've tried using another database without an underscore, naming it "testdb". I still get "Can't select database" error.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using

Comment: If your php is using `127.0.0.1` perhaps try that instead of `localhost` in your wordpress config and try again. Perhaps you have two root users in your database one `root@localhost` and one `root@127.0.0.1` and they have different permissions. That's a little far fetched, but mysql security is strange.

Comment: WAMPServer soes create 3 root accounts @JNevill one for `127.0.0.1` one for `localhost` and one for `::1` So you comment could well be very relevant

Comment: That's what I was remembering. It's been a long time since I monkeyed in mysql on WAMP. I think it's important to use the same ip/hostname and user as you are using for your `phpmyadmin` connection to insure that it's all 1:1. BETTER YET would be creating a new user in mysql like `wp_user@localhost` and granting it access to this new `test_db` database and then using that in the config of wordpress. Then it's nice and clear who has access to what.

Comment: I am using Wampserver Version 3.2.0 - 64bit

Comment: I tried using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" at WordPress setup and still got the same "Can't select database" error.

Comment: I tried this as the tutorial above instructed, and only tried changing privileges after it was suggested on the wordpress.org forum.

Comment: The phpMyAdmin page has "User: root@localhost" under Database server. I didn't set up any other users.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL or mariaDB

Comment: When I start up phpMyAdmin I enter Username: root I leave password blank and I select MySQL from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Try `define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3308' );` in the config. Or if you get asked about a port number during the install use 3308

Comment: When you say "in the config" do you mean the "my.ini" file? I couldn't figure out what you mean to edit. I went into WAMP, MySql 8.0.18, and edited the “my.ini” file. It opened in Notepad++ and I did a find and replace for all the “3308” into “localhost:3308”. I saved it and restarted WAMP, but WAMP wouldn’t start up all the way, it got stuck on orange. Luckily, I backed up the original my.ini file to my desktop.

Comment: I tried editing the wp-config manually: ` define( 'DB_NAME', 'localhost:3308' ); define( 'DB_USER', 'root' ); define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' ); define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' ); define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' ); define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );` I get this error message in my browser: "Error establishing a database connection"

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED!
During setup, wp-admin_setup-config.php_step=1, in the form for database connection details, I entered “**localhost:3308**” instead of “localhost” for **Database Host**.

Comment: Saved me after searching and searching thanks!!